# getting error while triggering this class

Tags: trigger

just now i came to know that we Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated i.e list here in my code, i m not getting any idea how to perform that, since i need to iterate all those child record type that are having master record type so that i can update date fields using master record dates, please anyone can help me out. here is my code

```
public class Close_Date_Updation
    {
        public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
        {  
          Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
          List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate,Master_Opportunity__c from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op];  //Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity self lookup

          for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){ 

              opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);  
                rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
                rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
                rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);
                   childRecord.add(rt); //I am declaring this list


           }

            upsert childRecord;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to add records in  the list again, as "rt" is an instance  variable present in the list you are iterating,so any changes you make will automatically be reflected in that instance of opportunity.

```
public class Close_Date_Updation
    {
        public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
        {  
          Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
          List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate,Master_Opportunity__c from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op];  //Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity self lookup

          for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){ 

              opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);  
                rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
                rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
                rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);
                   //childRecord.add(rt); //you dont need this line


           }

            upsert childRecord;
       }

}
```

Comment: okay no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need this statement `childRecord.add(rt);`

You simply achieve it without it as:

```
    public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
    {  
      Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
      List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate,Master_Opportunity__c from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op];  //Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity self lookup

      for(Opportunity rt : childRecord)
      { 
            opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);  
            rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
            rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
            rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);
      }

     upsert childRecord;
   }
```